# Labelling Segments in Turtle

Tags: python, label, turtle-graphics

The following is using Python's Turtle.

I'm trying to put pre-set labels (which are located in a list) next to the corresponding sections on a pie chart I've made in Turtle. The figures change the chart so I need the labels to not be in one place but rather move depending how big each segment of the pie chart is.

This is where I'm stuck. Should I def() so each set of lists change with only one function?
So far I have this:

```
groups = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D']
percentages = [0.2, 0.4, 0.15, 0.25]

def label():
    penup()
    for percent in percentages:
        setheading((percentages[0] * 360)/2)
        forward(radius + 20)
        color("Black")
        write(groups[0], False, "left", font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
        end_fill() 
label()
```

I plan to have 4 of this for each group. But what if there are more than 4 in the groups? And I think it loops because it prints the first group name (Group A) every 20 pixels. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Picture of what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6nyA.png

Answer (score 0):

Um, it's heading off diagonally right cause at the end of your loop - you never made the turtle GOTO the middle of the circle.

setheading isn't going to get that turtle heading in the direction you're hoping for either - setheading points to degrees on a 360 degree circle. 0 = east, 90 = north, 180 = west, 270= south.

You want to make your turtle turn for each value in percentage.  I would do that by starting having a value, eg `newheading=0` before the start of your `for percent in percentages:`
that way you can change `((percentages[0] * 360)/2)` to `((percentages[newheading]*360)/2)`
of course you need to know how to keep adding a value to that `newheading` value each time it passes through the loop.  Hopefully this advice can get you thinking towards how to make this work.

Comment: Yup, I managed to make an thing to update the variables you suggested, thanks!. Regarding the setheading, instead should I add the percentages in degrees to the one before it, or is there an easier way to calculate which angle to place the label?

Comment: You could do something like:
`half_angle=percent*360/2`
and then 
`lt(half_angle)` at the start of your loop
make it go and execute your label code, and then
`goto(0,0)`
and then make it complete the rest of your angle by
`lt(half_angle)`
that way, each cycle, it moves half way into each angle of your pie chart pice, pops just out of the pie chart, writes your label, heads back to the middle, turns it's heading to the remaining half of your pie chart piece, and starts all over again with the next loop for your next values.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the 1st post. How do I make all the groups appear at the same time groups = ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D']

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to address the label issue by taking on the whole pie chart as I don't think there should be separate `groups` and `percentages` lists but one combined data structure of labels and slice percentages. The following draws a pie chart in three passes -- the labels are written on the edges of an imaginary circle of greater radius by splitting the slices in half and labeling at the center:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from operator import itemgetter

FONT = ("Arial", 15, "bold")
LABEL_OFFSET = 1.33

pie_slices = {'Group A': 0.2, 'Group B': 0.4, 'Group C': 0.15, 'Group D': 0.25}

def pie_chart(turtle, radius, slices, font):

    # Pass 1: the pie itself
    x, y = turtle.position()
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(y - radius)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(radius, steps=60)  # steps setting improves smaller charts
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.penup()

    # Pass 2: the slices
    for _, percentage in slices:
        turtle.circle(radius, extent=360 * percentage)
        position = turtle.position()
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(position)

    # Pass 3: the labels
    radius *= LABEL_OFFSET
    turtle.sety(y - radius)
    for label, percentage in slices:
        turtle.circle(radius, extent=180 * percentage)
        # should do smarter label alignment to reduce LABEL_OFFSET
        turtle.write(label, align="center", font=font)
        turtle.circle(radius, extent=180 * percentage)


yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.color("black", "orange")
yertle.speed("fastest")
yertle.width(2)

# pie_chart() expects list of pairs, sort our dictionary by slice size into list
sorted_slices = sorted(pie_slices.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

pie_chart(yertle, 150, sorted_slices, FONT)

yertle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

This code's behavior depends somewhat on how you setup your slices (sorted, unsorted) and how you setup the turtle beforehand (pen color, fill color, width, initial position, speed, visibility, etc.)

OUTPUT

[image]